# Ubuntu 16.04 Freezes often

Tags: 16.04

I just installed Ubuntu 16.04 on a Gigabyte PC. Installation went without any issues. This OS is fantastic. I just have one problem, it freezes often usually while browsing the Internet.Can someone please steer me in the right direction?

Comment: How much RAM? Which browser?

Answer (score 4):

Since it's a Gigabyte PC I presume it is Intel-based.
Look in the comment section for changing "intel_idle.max_cstate", in the following bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1503731.

Another bug report in kernel bugzilla: https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=109051.

You can have a go in installing a newer kernel version kernel, I read somewhere this might be fixed in newer kernel versions(4.5 and up), here is a guide: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/MainlineBuilds.

Hope it helped.

Edit:
Open terminal, `Ctrl + Alt + T`
Use `sudo nano /etc/default/grub` to open grub configuration file.
Replace the line:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

with this line:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash intel_idle.max_cstate=1"
```

Press `Ctrl + x` then "Y" (for yes, to save, and press enter), then type `sudo update-grub`, enter password if needed and press enter.
After Grub updated restart and hope it worked.

I also recommend closing the PCs if they are not needed, as this solution will only extend the duration until they freeze.

Comment: Thank you so much for all the questions, comments and suggestions. I am using 8 Gigs of RAM. The Browser is Firefox and the Mouse stops moving entirely. By the way, I installed Ubuntu 16.04 on two new Gigabyte PCs , one with a SSD of 120 GB (ADATA),  the other with a 240 GB SSD (Kingstone). They both freeze. The one with the 240 GB SSD about once every 24 hours. The one with the 120 GB SSD about once every 1-2  hours.  Again, thank you for your answers.

Comment: Hello Wilfredo, try the edited solution and let me know if it improved your uptime.

Comment: same problem here. let's test the solution

Comment: Had same problem, tried the grub option, and also disabled Intel virtualization in the BIOS, and the system can now play video for hours without freeze. Now of course I don't know which of the two changes was most effective . . . (Intel Celeron J1900 Atom)

Answer (score 0):

My problem seemed to be Nouveau graphics drivers. First i updated kernel from 4.4 to 4.7-RC4 but it didn't help. Then I changed the graphics drivers from Nouveau to nvidia-340 and the random crashes seems to be gone...

1. System Settings -> Software & Updates -> Additional Drivers: 
   Using NIVIA binary drirver - version 340.96 from nvidia-340 (open source)
2. reboot