# How do I debug when the system freezes?

Tags: 16.04

How can I try to resolve this freeze problem?
From here [Ubuntu 16.04 Freezes often](https://askubuntu.com/questions/778045/ubuntu-16-04-freezes-often)
And following the instruction here I was able to obtain the crash report mentioned., [How do I debug when the system freezes or when it crashes back to login?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38367/how-do-i-debug-when-the-system-freezes-or-when-it-crashes-back-to-login/38369#38369).
But I don't know what I'm looking for, 
Gigabyte GA-990FX with recent installed G.SKILL Ripjaws Z Series 32GB (4 x 8GB) 240-Pin DDR3 SDRAM DDR3 2400 (PC3 19200). on a AMD FX9590 CPU that can only reach DDR3-1866, 64bit.
usr_bin_gdb_1000.crash is 23MB long.

Terminal output:

br116@br116:~$ ls -ltrh /var/crash/

total 51M

-rw-r----- 1 br116    whoopsie 1000K May 15 20:08 _usr_lib_gvfs_gvfsd-afp.1000.crash

-rw-rw-r-- 1 br116    whoopsie     0 May 15 20:08 _usr_lib_gvfs_gvfsd-afp.1000.upload

-rw------- 1 whoopsie whoopsie     0 May 15 20:43 _usr_lib_gvfs_gvfsd-afp.1000.uploaded

-rw-r----- 1 br116    whoopsie   23M May 16 21:26 _usr_bin_gdb.1000.crash

-rw-rw-r-- 1 br116    whoopsie     0 May 16 21:26 _usr_bin_gdb.1000.upload

-rw------- 1 whoopsie whoopsie     0 May 16 21:26 _usr_bin_gdb.1000.uploaded

-rw-r----- 1 br116    whoopsie   27M May 16 21:26 _usr_lib_banshee_Banshee.exe.1000.crash

-rw-rw-r-- 1 br116    whoopsie     0 May 16 21:26 _usr_lib_banshee_Banshee.exe.1000.upload

-rw------- 1 whoopsie whoopsie     0 May 16 21:26 _usr_lib_banshee_Banshee.exe.1000.uploaded

apport log:

ERROR: apport (pid 27370) Tue May 16 21:23:05 2017: wrote report /var/crash/_usr_lib_banshee_Banshee.exe.1000.crash

ERROR: apport (pid 27413) Tue May 16 21:25:39 2017: called for pid 27411, signal 6, core limit 18446744073709551615

ERROR: apport (pid 27413) Tue May 16 21:25:39 2017: ignoring implausibly big core limit, treating as unlimited

ERROR: apport (pid 27413) Tue May 16 21:25:39 2017: executable: /usr/bin/gdb (command line "gdb --ex file\ "/usr/bin/mono-sgen" --ex core-file\ /tmp/apport_core_r4jf1unc --batch --ex set\ backtrace\ limit\ 2000 --ex p\ -99 --ex x/16i\ $pc --ex p\ -99 --ex thread\ apply\ all\ bt\ full --ex p\ -99 --ex print\ __abort_msg->msg --ex p\ -99 --ex bt\ full --ex p\ -99 --ex info\ registers --ex p\ -99 --ex print\ __glib_assert_msg --ex p\ -99 --ex print\ (char*)\ __nih_abort_msg")

Comment: Edit your question to include the `terminal` output of `ls -alt /var/crash`.

Comment: Please edit your output to preserve the original formatting. Then look, really look at each line of output. Notice how the name of the application (like Banshee) is right there in the name of the crash file? Which application do you want to debug? Pick one of those files and open it in a text editor (not a word processor). Then start reading and search-engine the terms you don't understand.

Comment: Were you trying to debug Banshee? Is that when it froze? Start comments directed to me with `@heynnema` or I may miss them.

Comment: @heynnema.
No, Banshee wasn't even running at the time. I'm curious about the other lines.
ERROR: apport (pid 769726) Fri Aug  1 00:47:56 2014: ignoring implausibly big core limit, treating as unlimited. In which I can't find an answer.

Comment: Were you using gdb? Do you have Banshee installed on your computer? I don't understand why it would be a .exe file anyway. Do you have WINE installed?

Comment: @heynnema. No I was not using gdb. Yes banshee is installed and it crashes/causes problem with my S5 phone and now with the WD NAS Cloud, but as I mentioned it was not even running at the time and it works without those 2 present. No, no WINE.

Comment: Try running for a brief period in the Guest account and see if it freezes. How often does it freeze?

Comment: After sometime away abroad I'm back to report that even on the Guest account the freezing is continuous. Now I'm not even running Firefox nor any video.
I replaced my new G.SKILL Ripjaws Z Series 32GB (4 x 8GB) 240-Pin DDR3 SDRAM DDR3 2400 (PC3 19200) with the old modules (unknown brand) and no crash has happened.
Not even on Windows. No crash report has been produced (can't find one dated recently).

Comment: update: Bad Mobo/Memory combination. place the old DDR3 back and no more freezes occurred .